# Initializing a member of a structure with pointers (C)

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm a begginer and have been reading books on C, I have a question about pointers of structures. 
Below I tried to initialize members of the structure using a "*p" pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct part{
int num;
char *name;
};

int main()
{
   struct part *p;    //creating a pointer with 'struct part' type

   p->num= 5;          //initializing
   p->name= "Jose";

   printf("%d\n",p->num);
   printf("%s",p->name);

   return 0;
}
```

Probably a dumb question but I'm interest to know why is it wrong? The program  is crashing obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a pointer but it doesnt point to anything.

You'd have to do e.g. `p = malloc(sizeof(struct part))` or maybe `struct part q; p = &q;` or otherwise set it to point to something first.

Check out the C version of [this old classic](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/).

Comment: thanks for the help. Can I ask you as question.. When you set your pointer to a type 'struct part', wouldn't this information make the compiler  know how much space in memory your pointer variable will occupy? why would you need to explicitly do malloc?

Comment: @tadm123 Before I answer that: Did you watch the video?

Comment: Ok just watched it. I see now, I guess they are pointing at nothing and you can't give values to nothingness.. thanks, good video too lol

Comment: Would this be fair? p=malloc(sizeof(*p))

Comment: @tadm123 Exactly. And yeah that videos great, lol. Your pointer variables actually do have a size themselves, they are really just memory addresses, and their size is equal to whatever the size of a memory address is on that platform (e.g. 4 bytes on a 32 bit system). You can see this if you use sizeof on one. But unless they contain a valid address of *something*, you can expect binky to die a painful death when you dereference them.

Comment: @tadm123 Yeah that works although it's kinda strange, at least imho. It's a bit more idiomatic to use `sizeof(your type)`. But I'm sure you can find opinions both ways. It does work though.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer is not initialized. It does not point to a valid memory so you cannot reference struct members thru it. Do something like

```
struct part *p = malloc(sizeof(struct part));
```

(if this is the actual example in this C book - look for a better book?)

Comment: Nope it is just me trying doing trial/error of the concepts writing different codes. Appreciate the help though, I can see why now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>

struct part 
{
  int num;
  char *name;
};

int main()
{

struct part *p = (struct part*)malloc(sizeof(struct part)); //memory allocation

p->num = 5;
p->name = "Jose";          //initializing

printf("%d\n", p->num);
printf("%s", p->name);

return 0; }
```

Try this out